# LibraryThing ThingAuth

Tags: api

I have to work with [LibraryThing API](http://www.librarything.com/) and I did exactly what [LibraryThing'document](http://www.librarything.com/services/thingAuth/) said.

But after authorization step, I want to make a API call to access member's account infomations, they didn't provide me an API url.

Anybody have any solution for this stuff?